# discord bot. react by extracting data from database and embed it

Tags: python, database, discord, bots, embed

I installed a discord bot and a sql database with data inside
like this

```
id   | CATEGORIE |   RANK   | SCORE
1    |   156     |   466    |  65
2    |  4554     |   455    |  455
3    |   74      |    78    |  444
```

I want when someone type ?1 in a channel bot respond with an embed with all datas from line 1

when ?2 ---> embed all data from line 2

I have this base

```
    if message.content.startswith('?1'):
        rows = cursor.execute("SELECT #, CATEGORIE, RANK, SCORE, end FROM test").fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            embed = discord.Embed(title='test', color=0x0000FF)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://www.pngkit.com/png/detail/231-2316751_database-database-icon-png.png')
            embed.add_field(name='id', value=row[0], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='CATEGORIE', value=row[1], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='RANK', value=row[2], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='SCORE', value=row[3], inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(icon_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1325672283881484289/oaGtVIOD_400x400.png', text='Created by @Expected')
            msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            await msg.add_reaction('\U0001F5D1')
```

but it's not good at all....
I have no idea how to extract the lines by id in reaction to a message. I would need help I tried to find answers on the internet and on this site but I did not find and I do not know python well.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sorry, but what is your query? // Are you trying to get the ID number from the reaction emoji? // Your current 'base' code ends by reacting to the sent message with a trash can. Are you trying to listen for someone to react to that message? // Your description says `?1` as the command, but your code listens for a `$1`. Is that a typo or is that a different functionality?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake I correct !!
and this code is wrong it doesn't work at all
i want when someone in a channel type ?1 that line 1 appear embed

when ?2 --> embed line 2

?3 --> embed line 3

Comment: That would be because currently you're `for` looping through every row in the table. Try changing out the `for row in rows` line to something that picks out the specific line.

Comment: sorry I am not experiment at all! I need more explainations

Comment: I have not been able to solve this problem yet... waiting for help !